# Avoid page break in table with rowspan on print

Tags: html, printing, html-table, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

The table row will overflow table head when page breaks on print. I tried page-break-inside: avoid, but not working.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdXd3.jpg)

Added some code, the  is dynamically changed. On print when page break point is at rowspan part, always causes problems.

```
    <table class="table table-bordered reportTable" id="contentToConvert">
      <thead style="text-align: center" class="report-container">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" rowspan="2" style="width: 10%; vertical-align: middle;">Order #</th>
          <th scope="col" rowspan="2" style="width: 20%; vertical-align: middle;">Customer Information</th>
          <th scope="col" rowspan="2" style="width: 9%; vertical-align: middle;">Package(s)</th>
          <th scope="col" colspan="5" style="width: 61%; vertical-align: middle;">Package Information</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 17%; vertical-align: middle">Tracking Number</th>
          <th style="width: 10%; vertical-align: middle">Size</th>
          <th style="width: 10%; vertical-align: middle">Weight</th>
          <th style="width: 14%; vertical-align: middle">Instructions</th>
          <th style="width: 10%; vertical-align: middle">Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3" style="text-align: center; padding-left: 0rem; padding-right: 0rem">RetailOrder_0023
          </td>
          <td rowspan="3" style="padding-left: 1rem">
            George Jason <br>
            123 Arlington street <br>
            Arlington VA 22222<br>
            123-456-7890<br>
            GEORGE.Jason@gmail.com
          </td>
          <td rowspan="3" style="text-align: center">3</td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0">5134134231231261341231</td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">5 / 5/ 5 inches</td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">10 lbs 10 oz</td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"></td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Delivered</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0">018635013640123401234</td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">5 / 5/ 5 inches</td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">10 lbs 10 oz</td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Leave at front door</td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Delivered</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0">018635013640123401234</td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">5 / 5/ 5 inches</td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">10 lbs 10 oz</td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"></td>
          <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Delivered</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Show the simplest code that we can run that demonstrates the problem. Also, what browser?

Comment: The problem is on Chrome, I edited the question to add some codes, the screenshot is the same thing with code.

Comment: hi @EthanGong, did you find any work around?

Comment: I have same issue with my code. Anyone found the solution?